# Why doesn't the border appear when I use gradient as a fill color?

Tags: android, linear-gradients, android-vectordrawable

For my project I want to use a vector image for an icon, but I have run into an issue. When I use a gradient for `android:fillColor` like the code beneath the border which is defined by `android:strokeColor` and `android:strokeWidth` doesn't appear in the app. When add the `android:fillColor` directly to the `path` it works, but then I lose my gradient.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    android:width="32dp"
    android:height="56dp"
    android:viewportHeight="56.0"
    android:viewportWidth="32.0">
    <path
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M4,1L28,1A3,3 0,0 1,31 4L31,52A3,3 0,0 1,28 55L4,55A3,3 0,0 1,1 52L1,4A3,3 0,0 1,4 1z"
        android:strokeColor="#000000"
        android:strokeWidth="1.4">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient
                android:endX="17.0"
                android:endY="56.0"
                android:startX="17.0"
                android:startY="2.0"
                android:type="linear">
                <item
                    android:color="#FFFFFFFF"
                    android:offset="0.0" />
                <item
                    android:color="#FFD1D2D1"
                    android:offset="1.0" />
            </gradient>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    ...
</vector>
```

This is what I get now on my Nexus 5X and Pixel 2 XL emulator:

[image: icon without borders]

This is what I want to achieve. This is part of a screenshot I took from Android Studio, which renders the vector correctly:

[image: icon with borders]